# inno setup compiled exe is not installing app on Windows 8 64 bit, unsupported 16 bit application

Tags: installation, 64-bit, inno-setup, 16-bit, incompatibility

I created a setup file using innoIDE v1.0.0.0078 and sent it to our client but he is unable to install our 64-bit application. It won't load setup and I get the message: 'Unsupported 16-bit application. The programme or feature "\??\C:\Setup.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatability with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.' What can I do to make installer work on 64-bit Windows? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Inno Setup is not a 16-bit application.  Therefore one of two things has happened:

1. The download was corrupted and Windows doesn't recognise it as a valid application.  In this case, get your client to download it again (and check the version you uploaded too, maybe the problem happened then).
2. You are trying to run a 16-bit subinstall from within your Inno script.  Rewrite your setup to avoid doing that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What is "16-bit subinstall" and how to avoid doing this next time? many thanks.

Comment: I meant using `[Run]` or code to execute a program from your install process that happens to be 16 bit.  16-bit apps run ok on 32-bit Windows but not on 64-bit Windows.